# Unreliable DateTime parsing by COleDateTime

Tags: c++, mfc, ole, coledatetime

I am trying to parse the date using `ParseDateTime` method provided by `COleDateTime` class. But parsing of two different dates in the same program is returning inconsisent values for the month.

**Code Snippet:**

```
COleDateTime dtCreated;
dtCreated.ParseDateTime(safe_cast<CString>(strCreatedDate));
```

**Inconsistent RESULTS:**

if `strCreatedDate` = "10/7/2020" (in **mm.dd.yyyy** format)
then `dtCreated.GetMonth()` = 7 (**but it should be 10**)

if `strCreatedDate` = "7/29/2020" (in **mm.dd.yyyy** format)
then `dtCreated.GetMonth()` = 7 (in this case, it is **correct**)

**UPDATE:**

The value of date present in the `strCreatedDate` vairable could be "dd.mm.yyyy" OR "mm.dd.yyyy" format. But I do have the information about the data format available in a separate variable. Based on the format, I want `COleDateTime` to correctly parse the DateTime string. How can I do that?

Comment: Try to use LCID parameter.

Comment: @Dialecticus: I do have the information about the date format (dd.mm.yyyy OR mm.dd.yyyy) available in another variable. Can I somehow specify the correct format to use for the `ParseDateTime()`? The date is received from a server and it could be in (dd.mm.yyyy OR mm.dd.yyyy) format.

Comment: Okay if you have a bool, and you have only one exact format based on that bool then parse the date yourself with `sscanf`, or anything else you want. You get three values, and call `SetDateTime` with them.

Comment: Date and time parsers have a history of producing [unexpected results](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200929-05/?p=104313). It's not something I would rely on. I'd probably just write my own parser, really just a string split, followed by 3 applications of one of the [`stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) family of functions.

Comment: BTW what kind of an object is `strCreatedDate`? This `safe_cast` looks out of place in this question.

Comment: @Dialecticus: `strCreatedDate` is of type `String^`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `String^` is your input you could use `DateTime::ParseExact`, and then convert `DateTime` to `COleDateTime` using `DateTime.ToOADate`:

```
COleDateTime dtCreated(DateTime::ParseExact(
    strCreatedDate, isDMY ? "d.M.yyyy" : "M.d.yyyy", nullptr).ToOADate());
```

Comment: Why are you answering with a Managed C++/CLI answer, when the question is about Visual C++/MFC?!

Comment: @sergiol because OP mentioned in the comments that `strCreateDate` is `String^`, which is logical when you notice `safe_cast` in the question. While the question itself can be viewed and answered strictly as MFC it can also be viewed and answered as C++/CLI + MFC. I chose the latter.

Comment: `String^` could be C++/CLI or C++/CX though. Those are vastly different platforms, runtimes, and support libraries.

Comment: My source string (`String^ strCreateDate`) is indeed in C++/CLI. But with this implementation, it is throwing an exception, `{"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}`

Comment: Ok, the question comments were collapsed and I didn't see it. I could also deduce it from the question's `safe_cast`.

Comment: @user2756695 since there are no leading zeros in the date it's better to use formats "d.M.yyyy" and "M.d.yyyy". I updated the answer.

Comment: @Dialecticus: It worked. Actually,  instead of using the boolean variable to create the format, I am directly passing the format to the `DateTime::ParseExact()`.